# How to parse json object twig

Tags: json, symfony, twig

I try to parse a json in my view.
I did this in my controller

```
    /**
 * @Route(path="/newadmin/invoice/showAllContract", name="showAllContract")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function viewContract(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $template_id = $request->get('user');
    $getName = explode(" ", $template_id);
    $firstname = $getName[0];
    $lastname = $getName[1];
    $templateRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(ClientContract::class)->getListPerUser($firstname, $lastname);

    return new JsonResponse(json_encode($templateRepository));
}
```

It returns me a json that I want to use in my twig.

```
                {{ form_start(createInvoice) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.daysWorked) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.bankHolidays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.workSaturdays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.workSundays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.user) }}
           {#      my contract          #}
            {{ form_end(createInvoice) }}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#invoice_manual_creation_user').change(function (message) {
            $('#hidden').show();

            let userName = $('#invoice_manual_creation_user option:selected').text();
            console.log(userName)

            $.get("{{ path('showAllContract') }}", {'user': userName})
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated in furthering my understanding.

EDIT :

Thank you for your help I should have added some details.

I'm trying to get a contract avalable ony when you choose an associated user , that's why I did this in my repository :

```
    /**
 * @param $firstname
 * @param $lastname
 * @return mixed
 * @throws DBALException
 */
public function getListPerUser($firstname, $lastname)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = '
        SELECT clientname 
        FROM contact_end_client c
        INNER JOIN client_contract cli ON cli.clientname_id = c.id AND  cli.active
        INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = cli.user_id
        WHERE u.firstname = :firstname AND u.lastname = :lastname AND cli.active = 1
        ';

    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
    $param = ['firstname' => $firstname, 'lastname' => $lastname];
    $stmt->execute($param);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 1 improvement Solution

- in your controller

if you don't know symfony **ParamConverter**, you have to see it, it will help you a lot..and for understand why
i used {id} wildcard  **/newadmin/invoice/{id}/showAllContract** & **viewContract(User $user...)**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/newadmin/invoice/{id}/showAllContract", name="show_all_contract")
 * @param User $user
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function viewContract(User $user,Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   

    $templateRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(ClientContract::class)->getListPerUser($user->getFirstname(), $user->getLastname());

    return new JsonResponse(['templateRepository' => $templateRepository]);
}
```

- in template.twig

```
<select id="invoice_manual_creation_user">
    <option data-link="{{ path('show_all_contract',{'id' : createInvoice.user.id}) }}">Firstname Lastname</option>  
</select>

//...

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#invoice_manual_creation_user').change(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            
            $('#hidden').show();         
            var path  = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-link');


           $.post(path, function(data) {
               var templateRepository = data.templateRepository; 
                    // do what you want with your data
              });

        });

    });
</script>
```

### 2 for your Solution

- in template twig

```
            {{ form_start(createInvoice) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.daysWorked) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.bankHolidays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.workSaturdays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.workSundays) }}
            {{ form_row(createInvoice.user) }}

            // your list contract here
             <ul id="my-contract-list">
               
            </ul> 
            
            {{ form_end(createInvoice) }}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#invoice_manual_creation_user').change(function(message) {
        $('#hidden').show();

        let userName = $('#invoice_manual_creation_user option:selected').text();
        console.log(userName);

        const url = "{{ path('showAllContract',{'user': " + userName + "}) }}";

        $.get(url, function(data) {
            var myContractListUl = $("#my-contract-list");

            // if data is empty
            if (data.length === 0) {

                var li = $('<li></li>').text('Contracts not found');
                myContractListUl.append(li);
                return;
            }
            // we loop data and for each item we create li and append it to ul (my-contract-list)
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                var li = $('<li></li>').text(item.clinentName);
                myContractListUl.append(li);
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I can't do $user->getFirstname(). I edited my post.

Comment: @nolifegeek , i don't understand where is your probleme exactly ?

Comment: I have a json ( return new JsonResponse($templateRepository)) and I try to display it in my twig.
Again, thank for your time.

Comment: @nolifegeek I edit the answer , you can see the **2 for your Solution** part of answer , you are welcome :D

Comment: Thanks ! I did not use your code exactly but it helped me a lot to understand ! very grateful